# Error: Permission denied to access property '$'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

everybody.
I have the following situation:

I have:
http://example.com/ and http://example.com/new

In example.com, I have some forms that I load in example.com/new domain with fancybox iframe.

My form, basically shows some fields for the user to enter his pessoal data, like name, phone and etc... After he submit that, I show some user agreement terms that comes from database and a checkbox for the user to say that he agree with the terms.

After he check and submit, I want to alert some sucess message and the fancybox modal/iframe to close and thats it.

In the form page, i've loaded jquery, and bootstrap. So, when the user agree, I print:

```
<?php
     echo "
          <script>
          alert('Some success message!');

          $(document).ready(function(){
              parent.$.fancybox.close();
          });
         </script>
     ";
?>
```

I have three forms, in one, works, in the other two, i get:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property '$'
```

The only difference between the form that works and the other two, is that in the form that works, i don't have the agreement terms coming from database, only the checkbox.

I could put my entire code here, but would be a giant question. But if you guys need, I can update.

Sorry for my english and forgive-me if I was not clear.

**UPDATE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <?php
        /* Connect with DB */
        require_once('require/conectar.php');

        if(!empty($_POST))
            foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
                $$k = $v;
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/new/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php if(!isset($agree) and !isset($next)):     ?>
    <h1>The form</h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <label>Your name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <br>
        <label>Your email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="next">
    </form>
    <?php
        else:
            $error = (!isset($name)) ? true : false;
            $error = (!isset($name)) ? true : false;

            if($error)
            {
                echo '<script>You must fill all fields before submit.</script>';
                exit;
            }

            $qrr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `terms`");
            $terms = mysql_fetch_object($qrr);
    ?>
        <h1>Terms:</h1>
        <?php echo $terms->content; ?>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" name="name">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" name="email">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="accept"> I agree.
            <input type="submit" name="agree">
        </form>
    <?php
        endif;
        if(isset($agree))
        {
            /*
                Here i mail me the user data.
            */

            echo "
                <script>
                alert('Soliciação Realizada com sucesso!');
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    parent.$.fancybox.close();
                });
                </script>
            ";
        }else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('You need to agree with the terms to proceed.');</script>";
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Depending on the exact domains in question, accessing one frame from another may or may not be possible.

Comment: there must be another difference, we'd need to see all the code so we could tell.  See if you can make a minimal example that still causes the issue.  As you're stripping stuff out you may realize which line really caused it.

Comment: You need to post the smallest example code that causes the issue or you're effectively asking people to guess what the issue could be from hundreds of possibilities.

Comment: there is something missing from your description. Sounds like iframe so be sure one isn't `www.example.com` and the other doesn't have `www` or `http` vs `https`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a browser security thing. While there's a few ways around it, the best one is probably to use the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.postMessage).

On your example.com parent page, add some code like this:

```
function handleMessageFromiFrame(event) {
  alert('Some success message: ' + event.data);
  //$.fancybox.close();
}

window.addEventListener("message", handleMessageFromiFrame, false);
```

And, then on your child example.com/new iframe, add code like this:

```
var parentOrigin = "*"; // set to http://example.com/ or whatever for added security.

function sendMessageToParent(){
  parent.postMessage("button clicked", parentOrigin);
}

$('#submit-btn').click(sendMessageToParent);
```

Here's an example of it in action:

- Parent example.com page: http://jsbin.com/hiqoyevici/1/edit?html,js,output
- Child example.com/new iframe: http://jsbin.com/goferunudo/1/edit?html,js,output

When you click the button in the child page, it uses `postMessage` to notify the parent. Then the parent listens for the message and does whatever action you want.